# Synchronise two service calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-services

I have navigation bar with a `login()` on it, and two services:

1. authentication.service
2. authorization.service

In `navbar.component` (`login()`)  I would call  the two services mentioned above but I need in `myLogin()` function execute first the authentication then wait until it finish then call the second service (authorization).

```
login() {

    this.auth.login();  // <---  void type

    this.user.authorization(nickname: string)  // <--- subscribe
       .subscribe(
         (result) => this.res = result,
         (err)    => console.error(err),
         ()       => console.log('done')
       )

}
```

For now, the `login()` does not wait the first service finish, and this is my problem. Any idea how to perform this task?

here is the auth.login() : <---- Authentication

```
export class AuthenticationService {
      userProfile: any;
      lock = new Auth0Lock('xxxx', 'yyyy', {});


  constructor(  ) {
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult: any) => {
          this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error:any, profile:any){

            if(error) {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            this.userProfile = JSON.stringify(profile);
            localStorage.setItem('profile', this.userProfile);
        });

      });

    });
  }

  login() {
    this.lock.show();
    })
```

And here is the user.auth() :   <--- Authorization

```
this.user.getUserbyUserName(this.profile.nickname))
      .subscribe(
        (result) => { 
                      if(result == null) {
                        this.checkUserResponse = 'unknow'; 
                      } else {
                        //this.checkuser = true ;
                        if(result.logged == true) {
                          this.checkUserResponse = 'logged';
                        } else this.checkUserResponse = 'ok';
                      }
                    },
        (err) => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done')
      );
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without a proper [mcve], but presumably you need to `.subscribe` to one service, and call the second in the callback.

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. I just wrote the login() and the 2 services (with just console.log on them)  don't have any full minimal verifiable example yet , i m struggling on that case on how to call function and wait then pass to another . Please if you have an example do not hesitate to show up it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your navbar component:

```
  login() {
        Observable.forkJoin(
            this.auth.login();
            this.user.authorization(nickname: string);
           ).subscribe((info) => {
             // info returns an array with two row, first contain result of 
             // this.auth.login() and second contains this.user.authorization(nickname).
         }
    }
```

Comment: the auth.login() is a void type as already mentioned , it will not return data

Answer (score -1):

```
  this.auth.login()
  .switchMap(this.user.authorization())
  .subscribe(
     (result) => this.res = result,
     (err)    => console.error(err),
     ()       => console.log('done')
   )
```

## After the new code is provided

You can warp lock events to promise and return a promise from login.

```
function login() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.lock.on('authenticated', resolve);
   this.lock.on('authorization_error', reject);
   this.lock.show();
 });
}

login()
 .then(() => this.user.authorization()}
 .catch(err => console.log('error'))
```

Comment: try it but got this : Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'void'. Any clue what's the problem with it ?

Comment: sorry, i did not notice that it is void. can u change this.auth.login() to return an observable or promise or callback?

Comment: What the best and sweet able for that case(obs/prom/cb) ? can you please submit an example ?

Comment: please post in the question how the current auth service looks like and i can try to change it

Comment: Here we go, I just posted the 2 currents services.

Comment: if i replace  the login() in AuthentiationService by your wrap lock , it gives an error in VS editor says that Unexpected token and putting  function in red

Comment: sorry but it is hard to debug like that. please create a plunker and i will try to fix it.

Comment: honestly  cannot do it in plunker, the reason why is that I used auth0 as external service for authentication and we need to install some npm like auth0 and jwt and i dont know how to do it in plunker.

Comment: work around : by just putting the authorization part inside lock.on function .